# For such $a,b,c$ show that $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 \geq6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If $a, b, c > 0$ , such that $( a^2 + 1 )( b^2 + 1 )( c^2 + 1 ) = 27$ , then prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 >= 6.$

My approach to this is that i cant interpret the given conditions. Im not able to figure out where to put the values and all. I know the formula used here will be AM >= GM. please help

Comment: You certainly don't need $a,b,c>0$. :)

Comment: Note that the square of any real number is $>0$; so the hypothesis of the AM-GM inequality theorem is satisfied. Considering consistency, I ain't gonna edit the OP's statement. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use log of base 10, you get 
\begin{equation} 
\frac{log(a^2 + 1) + log(b^2 + 1) +log(c^2 + 1)  }{3} = \frac{log(27)}{3}
\end{equation} 
Note that $log(x)$ is concave in $x$ and that sum of concaves is also concave so by Jensen's inequality:
\begin{equation} 
\frac{log(a^2 + 1) + log(b^2 + 1) +log(c^2 + 1)  }{3} = \frac{log(27)}{3}
\leq 
\frac{log(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 3)}{3}
\end{equation} 
Therefore,
\begin{equation} 
6=
\Big(
3 \big(10^{\frac{log(27)}{3}}\big) - 3 \Big)
\leq 
a^2 + b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}

Comment: Ive not studied logs but thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{(a^2 + 1) + (b^2 + 1) + (c^2 + 1)}{3} \geq \cdots \quad?
$$

Comment: Thats equal to cube root of (a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)

Comment: ...which you know is equal to the cube root of $27$

Comment: @user354545 Greater than or equal to.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the AM-GM inequality?

We have

$$
\frac{(a^{2}+1) + (b^{2}+1) + (c^{2}+1)}{3} \geq [(a^{2}+1))(b^{2}+1)(c^{2}+1)]^{1/3}
$$
by the inequality;
the right-hand-side term is $=3$ by assumption.
Hence
$$
a^{2}+1+b^{2}+1+c^{2}+1 \geq 3\cdot 3 = 9,
$$
implying that 
$$
a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} \geq 6.
$$

Comment: Got you thanks brother